# Pinning live items (subclass ParseObject) and immediately retrieving via fromPin(pinName) - the list is empty

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a very simple fragment that basically calls a method that tries to retrieve custom Parse objects from the internet, pin them and then reload a UI ListView with the pinned items whether or not the internet call succeeded (so there is a fallback caching mechanism in case there is no internet connection).

Here are the two key methods:

```
// This is called in onViewCreated() and onResume() of the fragment
private void reloadWalletsFromInternet() {
    ParseQuery<Wallet> queryLiveData = ParseQuery.getQuery(Wallet.class);
    queryLiveData.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Wallet>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<com.hasmobi.money.models.Wallet> list, ParseException e) {
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                for (final Wallet w : list) {
                    w.pinInBackground("wallets", new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            reloadWalletsFromLocalstore();
                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "no wallets retrieved from internet");
                reloadWalletsFromLocalstore();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void reloadWalletsFromLocalstore() {
    final ParseQuery<Wallet> queryLocalData = ParseQuery.getQuery(Wallet.class);

    queryLocalData.fromLocalDatastore();
    queryLocalData.fromPin("wallets");

    queryLocalData.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Wallet>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Wallet> list, ParseException e) {

            // Here I am receiving 0 items in "list" which is wrong
            // (e is "null")
        }
    });
}
```

Inside App.java (my custom Application base class) I've subclassed the Wallet class to be registered in Parse:

```
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Wallet.class);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "my keys", "my keys");
```

I've put a couple of strategic `Log.d()` lines on a few places and the code successfully runs through both methods and the for() loop inside `reloadWalletsFromInternet()` successfully runs and *appears* to pin each of the received Wallet objects in the pin group "wallets". However, the subsequent query for the pins in that group, made by `reloadWalletsFromLocalstore()` don't seem to be able to retrieve those Wallet objects.

Comment: i dont think you need this line queryLocalData.fromLocalDatastore();
Using only this works for me  queryLocalData.fromPin("wallets");

Comment: as a debuging step, try using queryLocalData.fromPin(); without specifying the pin name.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do the job. 
get rid of `queryLocalData.fromPin("wallets");`

```
private void reloadWalletsFromLocalstore() {
    final ParseQuery<Wallet> queryLocalData = ParseQuery.getQuery(Wallet.class);

    queryLocalData.fromLocalDatastore();


    queryLocalData.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Wallet>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Wallet> list, ParseException e) {

            // Here I am receiving 0 items in "list" which is wrong
            // (e is "null")
        }
    });
}
```